# How to calll a stored proc via nHibernate which returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I have a big stored procedure which updates lots of tables and return nothing. I want to call this stored procedure via nHibernate, unfortunately I couldn't find like `ExecuteNonQuery` in `iQuery`.

```
ISession session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
var iQuery = session
               .GetNamedQuery("UpdateBoards")
               .SetParameter("cId", cId, NHibernateUtil.Int32).???;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException was caught
  Message=Return types of SQL query were not specified[...
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried `session.Flush();` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`var iQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec UpdateBoards @cId=:cId")
    .SetInt32("cId", cId)
    .ExecuteUpdate();`

Comment: im using bhibernate v1.4 and it doesnt have ExecuteUpdate method. thanks for the help.